# how to make macvim as default application for .g4 files

Tags: macos, antlr, antlr4, macos-catalina, macvim

I have installed macvim on catalina. It works when I use it for text (*.txt) files, from terminal or finder. But for some file extensions, I see that it is not visible from finder (from the terminal it works fine).

For example, I have an antlr file Hello.g4, and when I "Get Info" on it and then "Open With", the Macvim option is not enabled, see image. So I am unable to set macvim as the default tool for a g4 file.

How do I make macvim as the default tool for g4?

More information (these were the instructions I have followed, as per [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61473/)):

- macvim was installed on Catalina, as "brew install macvim", under /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.2-163_2
- Then I made the following softlinks:
- ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.2-163_2/MacVim.app /Applications/MacVim.app
- ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.2-163_2/MacVim.app ~/Applications/MacVim.app

On a more general note, when I install a new tool, how does macos determine which extensions to apply it to? For example, I see that "Atom" is enabled for g4 files, why?

[image]

Comment: When viewing the "Open With" dialog, are you changing the `Enable: Recommended Applications` pop-up menu to say `Enable: All Applications`? That option (just under the app list) should let you select MacVim. Each app developer specifies which extensions the OS should associate with their app (see `CFBundleDocumentTypes` at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Enabling all applications still showed macvim as shaded, but at least now I could click on it. If you this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I posted an answer and added your info about the right-click.

Comment: as of 2023, the location of Homebrew apps has changed..  so this works on my mac `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/macvim/9.0.1677/MacVim.app /Applications/MacVim.app` -- but clearly will need updating when the version changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing the "Open With" dialog, are you changing the `Enable: Recommended Applications` pop-up menu to say `Enable: All Applications`? That option (just under the app list) should let you select MacVim. *Update: based on your feedback, sounds like people may also need to right-click on MacVim to select it in the list. Good tip!*

As for how MacOS determins which extensions apply to an app, each app developer specifies which extensions the OS should associate with (see CFBundleDocumentTypes at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685